# AWS CDK: Detected package version outside of dependency constraint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am currently working on [AWS moderization workshop](https://catalog.us-east-1.prod.workshops.aws/v2/workshops/5c59492e-fc61-4a7b-b08a-e0307b70f390/en-US/2-sql-server/vpc). When I add the Amazon.CDK.AWS.EC2 nuget library and build the application, I get the following errors:
The application uses the latest Amazon. CDK.Lib, Contructs, Amazon.CDK.AWS.EC2 libraries from Nuget. I have also tried to run the command `npm update -g aws-cdk` using troubleshooting steps documented in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/troubleshooting.html#troubleshooting_toolkit but that has not helped.

What am I missing?

**Build errors:**

```
Rebuild started...
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: NorthwindCdk, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
Restored C:\Users\12146\northwind-cdk\src\NorthwindCdk\NorthwindCdk.csproj (in 54 ms).
1>C:\Users\12146\northwind-cdk\src\NorthwindCdk\NorthwindCdk.csproj : warning NU1608: Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Amazon.CDK.AWS.EC2 1.137.0 requires Constructs (>= 3.3.69 && < 4.0.0) but version Constructs 10.0.22 was resolved.
1>C:\Users\12146\northwind-cdk\src\NorthwindCdk\NorthwindCdk.csproj : warning NU1608: Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Amazon.CDK.AWS.CloudWatch 1.137.0 requires Constructs (>= 3.3.69 && < 4.0.0) but version Constructs 10.0.22 was resolved.
1>C:\Users\12146\northwind-cdk\src\NorthwindCdk\NorthwindCdk.csproj : warning NU1608: Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Amazon.CDK.AWS.IAM 1.137.0 requires Constructs (>= 3.3.69 && < 4.0.0) but version Constructs 10.0.22 was resolved.
1>C:\Users\12146\northwind-cdk\src\NorthwindCdk\NorthwindCdk.csproj : warning NU1608: Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Amazon.CDK.AWS.KMS 1.137.0 requires Constructs (>= 3.3.69 && < 4.0.0) but version Constructs 10.0.22 was resolved.
1>C:\Users\12146\northwind-cdk\src\NorthwindCdk\NorthwindCdk.csproj : warning NU1608: Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Amazon.CDK.AWS.Logs 1.137.0 requires Constructs (>= 3.3.69 && < 4.0.0) but version Constructs 10.0.22 was resolved.
1>C:\Users\12146\northwind-cdk\src\NorthwindCdk\NorthwindCdk.csproj : warning NU1608: Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Amazon.CDK.AWS.S3.Assets 1.137.0 requires Constructs (>= 3.3.69 && < 4.0.0) but version Constructs 10.0.22 was resolved.
1>C:\Users\12146\northwind-cdk\src\NorthwindCdk\NorthwindCdk.csproj : warning NU1608: Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Amazon.CDK.AWS.S3 1.137.0 requires Constructs (>= 3.3.69 && < 4.0.0) but version Constructs 10.0.22 was resolved.
1>C:\Users\12146\northwind-cdk\src\NorthwindCdk\NorthwindCdk.csproj : warning NU1608: Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Amazon.CDK.AWS.SSM 1.137.0 requires Constructs (>= 3.3.69 && < 4.0.0) but version Constructs 10.0.22 was resolved.
1>C:\Users\12146\northwind-cdk\src\NorthwindCdk\NorthwindCdk.csproj : warning NU1608: Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Amazon.CDK 1.137.0 requires Constructs (>= 3.3.69 && < 4.0.0) but version Constructs 10.0.22 was resolved.
1>C:\Users\12146\northwind-cdk\src\NorthwindCdk\NorthwindCdk.csproj : warning NU1608: Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Amazon.CDK.Assets 1.137.0 requires Constructs (>= 3.3.69 && < 4.0.0) but version Constructs 10.0.22 was resolved.
1>C:\Users\12146\northwind-cdk\src\NorthwindCdk\NorthwindCdk.csproj : warning NU1608: Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Amazon.CDK.AWS.Events 1.137.0 requires Constructs (>= 3.3.69 && < 4.0.0) but version Constructs 10.0.22 was resolved.
1>C:\Users\12146\northwind-cdk\src\NorthwindCdk\NorthwindCdkStack.cs(7,38,7,43): error CS0433: The type 'Stack' exists in both 'Amazon.CDK.Lib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'Amazon.CDK, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
1>C:\Users\12146\northwind-cdk\src\NorthwindCdk\NorthwindCdkStack.cs(9,36,9,45): error CS0104: 'Construct' is an ambiguous reference between 'Amazon.CDK.Construct' and 'Constructs.Construct'
1>C:\Users\12146\northwind-cdk\src\NorthwindCdk\NorthwindCdkStack.cs(9,64,9,75): error CS0433: The type 'IStackProps' exists in both 'Amazon.CDK.Lib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'Amazon.CDK, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
1>Done building project "NorthwindCdk.csproj" -- FAILED.
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

**NorthwindCdk.cs:**

```csharp
using Amazon.CDK;
using Constructs;
using Amazon.CDK.AWS.EC2;

namespace NorthwindCdk
{
    public class NorthwindCdkStack : Stack
  {
        internal NorthwindCdkStack(Construct scope, string id, IStackProps props = null) : base(scope, id, props)
        {
      var vpc = new Vpc(this, "LabVpc", new VpcProps
      {
        MaxAzs = 2
      });
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is caused by the fact that you have both CDK v1 and v2 installed. In CDKv1, each module is its own package - the packages that are included in the error are all v1 (e.g.`Amazon.CDK.AWS.EC2`, `Amazon.CDK.AWS.Cloudwatch`, etc). With CDKv2, all these modules are included in the `Amazon.CDK.Lib` package, which you also have installed.

To be clear, CDKv1 is not deprecated, both are supported. But you cannot use both at the same time.

Comment: Thanks @gshpychka for your input.

Comment: you did. Thank you @gshpychka

Comment: this is so confusing! I'm trying to use the experimental [ApiGateway2 construct](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/dotnet/api/Amazon.CDK.AWS.Apigatewayv2.Alpha.html#websocket-api) and once I installed, I got ambiguous type errors. I don't know which CDK version it's using, how can I know?

Answer (score -1):

it seems that the `Amazon.CDK.AWS.EC2` nuget library is deprecated. I uninstalled the library and the application build and deployed correctly.

Comment: This is not correct, it's not deprecated. It's just part of CDKv1.